# Need Post Request format for Live app Insertion in quip via API

Tags: python, quip, liveapps

Is there an Example for insertion live app into Quip document via API

`Edit API`

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.7
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 896f63df-27ba-43dc-8328-62261456e276
Host: platform.quip.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 230
content=%3Cdiv%20id%20%3D'New%20Div'%20data-live-app%20type%3D%22salesforce_record%22%3E%20This%20is%20a%20new%20Div%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E&thread_id=bRhJA1JTE8BH&data=%7Borg_id%3A00D6g000000EZuvEAG%2Crecord_id%3A00Q6g000009ltzQEAQ%7D
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 23 Oct 2020 17:19:44 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 98
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 100
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 99
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1603473600
Retry-After: 17
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin
{"error":"application_error","error_code":400,"error_description":"`data-live-app` json decode error"}
```

`for Create API`

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.7
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 7a6a3c4f-791f-43aa-8d8c-07b9237a548a
Host: platform.quip.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 223
content=%3Cdiv%20id%20%3D'New%20Div'%20data-live-app%20type%3D%22salesforce_record%22%3E%20This%20is%20a%20new%20Div%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E&data=%7Borg_id%3A00D6g000000EZuvEAG%2Crecord_id%3A00Q6g000009ltzQEAQ%7D&title=New%20Doc
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Fri, 23 Oct 2020 17:22:01 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 57
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 100
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 99
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1603473780
Retry-After: 60
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin
{"error":"application_error","error_code":500}
```

Answer (score 0):

We've recently updated our docs to include an example of inserting live apps, along with an example of the initialization parameters we support for some apps:

https://corp.quip.com/dev/automation/documentation#edit-a-document

Relevant excerpt:

> You can insert a Live App into a document via a div tag with the
> following attributes:
>
> - data-live-app-id: The id of Live App you want to insert. eg.
>   XdJAjAN5Jbi
> - data-live-app-payload: JSON string containing all the details of the Live App to insert.
>
> See below for examples.
> eg. `<div data-live-app-id='XXXXX' data-live-app-payload='{"record_id":"YYYYY","org_id":"ZZZZZ"}' />`
>
> **Salesforce Record Live App**
>
> - data-live-app-id: XdJAjAN5Jbi
> - data-live-app-payload
>
>   - record_id: The Salesforce record ID to insert.
>   - org_id: The Salesforce org ID.
>
> **Salesforce List Live App**
>
> - data-live-app-id: QYUAjAGNxIo
> - data-live-app-payload
>
>   - Record List
>
>     - list_id: The Salesforce list ID to insert.
>     - object_type: Type of Object
>     - org_id: The Salesforce org ID.
>   - Related List
>
>     - record_id: The record ID.
>     - related_list_type: The related list view's object type associated to the record.
>     - org_id: The Salesforce org ID.
>
> We return the updated thread in the format specified in Get Thread

Comment: Thank you :), I have one question though is there a way in quip to add Salesforce report ? Programattically?

Comment: No, reports are not live apps, and we don’t currently have a way to insert them via the API.